# Как получить контент при появлении HTTP-ошибки

Tags: c#

допустим у меня есть такой запрос https://192.168.0.1:8443/reportRequest/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/reportResult?unpacked=true (REST Web Service, method Get) і такой код

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.0.1:8443/reportRequest/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/reportResult?unpacked=true");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
try { request.GetResponse(); }
catch { }
```

Как мне вывести в консоль:
HTTP/1.1 404
Content-Type : text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length : 43
Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0?

Или если был POST и запрос выполняется тогда возможны варианты: Request id: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 State: IN_PROGRESS или Request id: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 State: QUEUED

Comment: Тогда не вывести, а получить. Или на крайний случай - вывести в консоль. Я вначале думал, "как с сайта вывести" имеется ввиду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если статус не ОК, то c# генерирует исключение. Получить можно так:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ваш_адрес");
/// подготовить запрос
byte[] query = new byte[1024];// Пакет для буфера       
// Что б при пост-запросе не генерировалось 100-continue
((System.Net.HttpWebRequest)req).ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
System.Net.WebResponse res = null;
try{ 
   // Если пост запрос - нужно передать данные
   // req.Method = "POST"; - если пост
   // req.GetRequestStream().Write(query, 0, query.Length);                   
                res = req.GetResponse();

} catch (System.Net.WebException e)
            {
                res = e.Response;
                if (res == null) {}; // Тогда нету ответа
            };

// и например читать из стрима
i = res.GetResponseStream().Read(query, 0, query.Length);
// или в консоль
using (var streamReader = res.GetResponseStream()) {
 TextReader tr = new StreamReader(streamReader);   
 Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd()); 
 } 
// -------------------------
res.Close(); // обязательно закрыть запрос 
// Если забыть закрыть - можно долго странные глюки ловить потом
```

Стрим можно обрабатывать и другим способом. Из ответа res можно узнать и `StatusCode`  и другие параметры. Данный код является примером синхронного запроса, т.е. ответ вы получите тогда, когда с# поймет что он достиг конца запроса, или достигнуть его больше не может (например таймаут). Если нужно получать "частями" (большой файл например) - то нужно смотреть асинхронные методы.

Сгенерировать можно так.

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.StatusCode = 404;
 Response.Write("Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0");
 Response.End();
```

Если `Response` в программе по каким-то причинам недоступно, его всегда можно найти тут

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
```

Так же, можно менять ContentType, добавлять другие заголоки и т д, более подробно можно найти в MSDN
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse

Comment: мне не нужно самому туда это записать, мне надо это получить в соответствии на каком этапе запрос, его вообще нет, или он в очереди или он в процессе выполнения

Comment: Поправил, добавил код.

Comment: using (var streamReader = e.Response.GetResponseStream())
{
      TextReader tr = new StreamReader(streamReader);
      Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd());
} получил то что мне нужно было, спасибо

Comment: Я думаю, что нужно добавить `e.Response.Close()`. У меня без Close основного - программа переставала работать. За исключение - не тестил, можно ли Close опустить.